# Send request to api website and then api give me some data in array format, how to work with this data?

Tags: php, arrays

Send request to api website and then api give me some data in array format, how to work with this data ?

1. When I access to: `example.com/api.php?name=papaya`, it's will show

   `Array ( [0] => papaya [1] => fruit )`
2. in my site, I want to work with this array data like

   `$url = "example.com/api.php?name=papaya ";
   if ($url[1] == "fruit" )
      { echo "food"; }`

How to do that?

Comment: return your array with `json_encode()` link here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Consider returning as JSON rather than `print_r` the array.

Comment: You may want to read up on SOAP and REST and how they work

Comment: SOAP doesn't really have very much to do with this... SOAP is XML based, this would be better as JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guys aren't understanding what the OP is asking. He's asking how he can use the data that is returned from the `api request`. I don't think he has access to the API itself but rather the end-point.

### Now to answer the question.

Basically you'd need to either use [**`cURL`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or something like [**`file_get_contents()`**](http://www.php.net/function.file-get-contents).

For this example, I'm going to use `file_get_contents()` to give you a basic idea:
Now the below example will get the returned data from the `geoplugin.net` api.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$result = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip));

print_r($result);
?>
```

For your case, you'd do something similar:

```
    <?php 
    $result = @json_decode(file_get_contents("example.com/api.php?name=papaya"));
    // do what you need to with result...
    echo $result[0];
    ?>
```

Obviously this isn't the best way to do it; as you'd need to make sure there were no errors (suppressed the errors with the `@` before the `json_decode()`).


Now I'm not going spoon feed you, so here are some examples on how to do some `cURL` requests.

- [PHP.NET cURL Examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php)
- [Simple PHP cURL Example](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/curl-example.htm)
- [All examples of PHP cURL....](http://www.silverphp.com/php-curl-function-for-post-and-get-request.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the API, then set the response header Content-Type: application/json, then json_encode any output, and json_decode on the client side.

Otherwise theres not much you can do with that string.. possibly use a regex method to extract the key and values?